# How to correctly set values from JSON API response into Google Spreadsheet

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get data into my google sheets from this API, I want to set the values each one in one row and if possible split them in columns.

I tried this code below but what I get is that the script set the values each one in one column and whithout spliting the data.

[image: spreadsheet screenshot]

```
function myFunction() {
  
}

var urlRequest = 'https://www.presupuestoabierto.gob.ar/api/v1/credito?format=json'
      
var body = {
      "title": "Credito devengado",
      "ejercicios":[2020],
      "columns": [
       "impacto_presupuestario_mes",
        "ejercicio_presupuestario",
        "jurisdiccion_id",
        "jurisdiccion_desc",
        "servicio_desc",
        "inciso_id",
        "principal_desc",
        "credito_devengado",
        "ultima_actualizacion_fecha"],
      "filters": [
        {
                    "column": "inciso_id",
                    "operator": "equal",
                    "value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "column": "jurisdiccion_id",
                    "operator": "equal",
                    "value": "30"
                }
            ]
    }


var options = {
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {Authorization:'a......e','Content-Type':'application/json'},
    payload: JSON.stringify(body)
}

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlRequest, options);
var json = response.getContentText();
var dataAll = JSON.parse(json);
 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();


// I modified below.
var rows = [Object.keys(dataAll)]; // Retrieve headers.
var temp = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rows[0].length; i++) {
    temp.push(dataAll[rows[0][i]]); // Retrieve values.
  }
  rows.push(temp);
  sheet.getRange(1,1,rows.length,rows[0].length).setValues(rows); // Put values to Spreadsheet.
```

Comment: Tip: Checkout [tag:importjson].

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample input and output you expect? At the sample input, can you provide the sample value of `response` of `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlRequest, options);`? At the sample output, can you provide the sample output image you expect?